# Figuring out transistor function in schematic

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, schematics

I know some digital logic. Here is a simple Full adder schematic. It is easy to understand the digital part but i don't understand the logic of adding transistor on the sum output? What is the purpose of adding this transistor? Why **only** at the sum output? Why not the carry output as well.

[image: See below]

Any recommendations on how to nail down more sophisticated schematics?

Comment: As drawn the transistor and accompanying resistors do not make sense. The R2/1k load is switched on and off with the rhythm of the sum output, it is directly connected across the power supply. But a 1k resistor on its own doesn't do much af a practical job in this configuration.

Comment: Where did you find this schematic? Interpreting the nuances you're asking about depends very much on context.

Comment: You might be surprised but i took this figure from Cadence Orcad Schematic Flow tutorial

Comment: @DaveTweed, there is no nuance. As i said, the schematic is taken from a tutorial on how to draw a schematic using Cadence ORCAD software.

Comment: @jippie, assume that the schematic is wrong, which is unlikely. How would you add the transistor at the sum output in a meaningful way? Please educate me and the rest of the community

Comment: I wouldn't add a transistor at all, unless for educational purposes.

Comment: In that case, the transistor is there in order to show you how to put transistors (and resistors) into a circuit. It doesn't need to make sense in terms of how you'd actually build an adder circuit.

Comment: @DaveTweed, and jippie, The circuit is later simulated using SPICE. I don't agree. You can see DSTM probes on the inputs

Comment: The signal at Q1 collector is inverted with respect to the SUM output of the top half adder, but nothing is being done with the signal in this particular diagram.

Comment: @jippie, thank you and Dave for your responses. I am wondering can one just take a digital output and take it off-chip. I mean can one just take a digital output from the chip to the outside world as it is or should there be some amplification/analog thing? Doesn't transistor here fulfilling this requirement?

Comment: Most IC's are very sensitive, a transistor can help (act as a buffer) in that regard. The chip's datasheet will list these sort of specifications.

Comment: @jippie, can you mention transistor configuration when it acts as a buffer. Does it have to be like this (common emitter)?. Also put your answer as a reply so i can accept it and you may get some points.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_collector

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_emitter

Comment: /SUM appears at R2-Q1 intersection - add a line there and call it output ... | Add a series LED with R2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the circuit you posted, the transistor Q1 does not have a function.

Activation/deactivation of Q1 does not cause:

- any information to reach CON2.
- influence of any kind on other sub-circuits you have shown

If you think this is not so, you will have to show us more of your circuit.

Comment: Thank you for the "answer accepted", but if jippie post his anwer, you should reconsider.

Comment: Enjoy the rep. I'm having a lazy day ;o)

Answer (score 1):

R1, Q1 and R2 make up a TTL logic inverter, where R1 limits the base current and R2 is the load. However, the output is between Q1 and R2, and it is not indicated by a pin in the schematic.

The connector only connects to the supply rails. For what reason it is done like this, I cannot say.